# MSSQL query IN statement for distinct rows

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, relational-database

Okay so the problem I'm having is selecting a distinct property on the query below. I understand the reasoning behind why I can't (rownum is unique) but I'm after a solution that will allow me to keep my SQL paging and pull though only the distinct properties from my database. I'm currently using a one to many database relationships that also holds the filtering needed for the results. What I'd be interested in hearing is if there's a better way than using "IN" for my filtering. Cheers guys

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getActiveProperties]

@PAGENUM  AS INT,
@PERPAGE AS INT,
@SORTBY AS VARCHAR(50),
@FILTERBY AS VARCHAR(200)

AS

DECLARE @query as VARCHAR(2000)

SET @query = N'SELECT *
        FROM (SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @SORTBY + ') AS [rownum],
            dbo.funcSellIdByPropId(T0.id) as SellerId,
            dbo.funcDefaultImage(T0.id, 1) as propImage,
            dbo.funcDefaultImage(T0.id, 2) as propImage2,
            dbo.funcDefaultImage(T0.id, 3) as propImage3,
            dbo.funcDefaultImage(T0.id, 4) as propImage4,
            dbo.funcCountPropertyImages(T0.id) as imageCount,
            dbo.funcGetPropertyTypeListGB(T0.id) as TypeGB,
            dbo.funcGetPropertyTypeListFR(T0.id) as TypeFR,
            dbo.funcGetPropertyEnviListGB(T0.id) as EnviGB,
            dbo.funcGetPropertyEnviListFR(T0.id) as EnviFR,
            dbo.funcGetDepartmentByTown(T0.Town) as Department,
            dbo.funcCheckFeaturedProperty(T0.id) as Featured,
            T0.id, T0.Price, T0.BedRooms, T0.Town, T0.Postcode, T0.Mandate, T0.MinLandArea, T0.Rooms, T0.HabitableSurface, T0.Active, T0.Budget,
            T1.TitleFR, T1.TitleGB, SUBSTRING(T1.DescFR, 0, 300) as DescFR, SUBSTRING(T1.DescGB, 0, 300) as DescGB
        FROM
            PROPERTIES T0
        INNER JOIN
            PROPERTYTRANSLATIONS T1
        ON
            T1.PropertyId = T0.id
        INNER JOIN
            MATRIXPROPENVIRONMENT T2
        ON
            T2.PropertyId = T0.id
        INNER JOIN
            ENVIRONMENT T3
        ON
            T3.id = T2.EnvironmentId
        WHERE
            T0.Deleted = 0 
        AND 
            T0.Active = 1 
        AND
            T3.GB IN (' + @FILTERBY + ')

        ) T
    WHERE
        rownum BETWEEN (' + CONVERT(varchar(4), @PERPAGE * @PAGENUM) + ') AND (' + CONVERT(varchar(4), @PERPAGE * (@PAGENUM + 1)) + ')'

EXEC (@query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. Move rownum from the subquery to the outer query:

```
SET @query = N'SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @SORTBY + ') AS [rownum],
      *
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
            dbo.funcSellIdByPropId(T0.id) as SellerId,
            dbo.funcDefaultImage(T0.id, 1) as propImage,
            dbo.funcDefaultImage(T0.id, 2) as propImage2,
            dbo.funcDefaultImage(T0.id, 3) as propImage3,
            dbo.funcDefaultImage(T0.id, 4) as propImage4,
            dbo.funcCountPropertyImages(T0.id) as imageCount,
            dbo.funcGetPropertyTypeListGB(T0.id) as TypeGB,
            dbo.funcGetPropertyTypeListFR(T0.id) as TypeFR,
            dbo.funcGetPropertyEnviListGB(T0.id) as EnviGB,
            dbo.funcGetPropertyEnviListFR(T0.id) as EnviFR,
            dbo.funcGetDepartmentByTown(T0.Town) as Department,
            dbo.funcCheckFeaturedProperty(T0.id) as Featured,
            T0.id, T0.Price, T0.BedRooms, T0.Town, T0.Postcode, T0.Mandate, T0.MinLandArea, T0.Rooms, T0.HabitableSurface, T0.Active, T0.Budget,
            T1.TitleFR, T1.TitleGB, SUBSTRING(T1.DescFR, 0, 300) as DescFR, SUBSTRING(T1.DescGB, 0, 300) as DescGB
        FROM
            PROPERTIES T0
        INNER JOIN
            PROPERTYTRANSLATIONS T1
        ON
            T1.PropertyId = T0.id
        INNER JOIN
            MATRIXPROPENVIRONMENT T2
        ON
            T2.PropertyId = T0.id
        INNER JOIN
            ENVIRONMENT T3
        ON
            T3.id = T2.EnvironmentId
        WHERE
            T0.Deleted = 0 
        AND 
            T0.Active = 1 
        AND
            T3.GB IN (' + @FILTERBY + ')
        ) T ) TT
    WHERE
        rownum BETWEEN (' + CONVERT(varchar(4), @PERPAGE * @PAGENUM) + ') AND (' + CONVERT(varchar(4), @PERPAGE * (@PAGENUM + 1)) + ')'
```

Comment: I've just given it a go and I get back the following "Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 43
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified."

Comment: You are right. I have removed the ORDER BY from the sub-query

Comment: I now get "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 43
Invalid column name 'rownum'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 43
Invalid column name 'rownum'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 43
The multi-part identifier "T0.Price" could not be bound."

Comment: You are right again. I have added an extra level of sub-queries. Please have a look

Comment: Okay I'm getting an error with the SORTBY in the "SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @SORTBY + ') AS [rownum]" I was passing T0.Price but that's now inside the query for T so I've tried adding T.Price in the sort by and comes back with Msg 207, Level 16, "State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'Price'." Thank you for all your help so far man :)

Comment: Okay I've got it working but we've gone from 0.356 of a second to 4 seconds to get the same results. I think I might have to have a look at the IN statement? What would you suggest? I'll mark this question as answered in the mean time as the original question has been answered thanks :)

Comment: I think it is `DISTINCT`. When you introduce this keyword the RDBMS needs to retrieve all rows in the inner sub-query to populate the list. Try to remove it and check to prove if I am right. If it is the DISTINCT, try replacing it with a GROUP BY in the inner sub-query

Comment: You are spot on. Thank you very much indeed. Solved my problems and taught me something new. Thank you

Comment: Okay it seems by adding `GROUPING` or `MAX` to the rows also keeps the time to around the 5 seconds mark, basically it's the same as `DISTINCT`. Not really sure what else I can do to get the right results  :(