# Speeding up MSSQL SELECT DISTINCT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, relational-database

I've had this query working fine and under 1 seconds until I'd added a `DISTINCT` to the `SELECT` statement. I've tried `GROUP BY` and also tried `MAX` to each column. All of which still give the same amount of time 5+ seconds. If any one has any suggestions on how to make this run quicker I'd be massively grateful.

This is a follow on from the [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797972/mssql-query-in-statement-for-distinct-rows/22798064?noredirect=1#comment34765337_22798064)

```
  SET @query = N'SELECT * FROM (  
  SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @SORTBY + ') AS [rownum],  *  
  FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT  
              dbo.funcSellIdByPropId(T0.id) as SellerId,  
              dbo.funcDefaultImage(T0.id, 1) as propImage,  
              dbo.funcDefaultImage(T0.id, 2) as propImage2,  
              dbo.funcDefaultImage(T0.id, 3) as propImage3,  
              dbo.funcDefaultImage(T0.id, 4) as propImage4,  
              dbo.funcCountPropertyImages(T0.id) as imageCount,  
              dbo.funcGetPropertyTypeListGB(T0.id) as TypeGB,  
              dbo.funcGetPropertyTypeListFR(T0.id) as TypeFR,  
              dbo.funcGetPropertyEnviListGB(T0.id) as EnviGB,  
              dbo.funcGetPropertyEnviListFR(T0.id) as EnviFR,  
              dbo.funcGetDepartmentByTown(T0.Town) as Department,  
              dbo.funcCheckFeaturedProperty(T0.id) as Featured,  
              T0.id, T0.Price, T0.BedRooms, T0.Town, T0.Postcode,
              T0.Mandate, T0.MinLandArea, T0.Rooms, T0.HabitableSurface, 
              T0.Active, T0.Budget,  
              T1.TitleFR, T1.TitleGB, SUBSTRING(T1.DescFR, 0, 300) as DescFR,
              SUBSTRING(T1.DescGB, 0, 300) as DescGB  
          FROM  
              PROPERTIES T0
              INNER JOIN PROPERTYTRANSLATIONS T1 ON T1.PropertyId = T0.id  
              INNER JOIN MATRIXPROPENVIRONMENT T2 ON T2.PropertyId = T0.id
              INNER JOIN ENVIRONMENT T3 ON T3.id = T2.EnvironmentId  
          WHERE  
              T0.Deleted = 0    
              AND T0.Active = 1   
              AND T3.GB IN (' + @FILTERBY + ')  
    ) T ) TT  
  WHERE  rownum BETWEEN (' + CONVERT(varchar(4), @PERPAGE * @PAGENUM) + ') AND (' + CONVERT(varchar(4), @PERPAGE * (@PAGENUM + 1)) + ')'
```

### Passed Parameters

`@PAGENUM = 0`
`@PERPAGE = 20`
`@SORTBY = N'Price DESC'`
`@FILTERBY = N'''City'', ''Village'', ''Coastal'''`

### Result

[Download csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7zbngth456yk24w/test.csv)

Comment: Distinct, Max and Group ill try to compare or order by you result set. If you got a big result set CPU ill get a hard time ordering comparing the rows, even creating a hash for each row. Since you values come from functions and not columns indexing ill not help. Maybe you can "store" that dataset in a temporary table and create a index or hash column or both and use it to sort or even a fast forward cursor do do a insertion sort. All are long shots and maybe you just got a too big data set and is not feasible to process it in time

Comment: If you cannot solve the problem by speeding up the query you can try another approach like *argh!* denormalization or creating a SearchFromThisTable and update it each (put a time period here)

Comment: Why do you need `DISTINCT`? Maybe you just have to add a supplementary condition on JOIN with T1 or T2 or T3. Where does these duplicates rows are coming from?

Comment: Could you post a query plan to have a look at?

Comment: Add a CTE where you DISTINCT over the columns that really need to be distinct. Then use INNER JOIN to fetch the other fields.

Comment: Remove DISTINCT and save the results into a #temp table, then select from #temp with DISTINCT. Get rid of that ugly dynamic SQL while at it :)

Comment: I'll have a go at putting into a temp. Thanks guys. I've added parameters and result to my original post to possibly help you understand situation.

Comment: The bad code smell is all those functions -- are you sure you can't get rid of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, as stated in the comments don't run the functions on everything, only what you are going to return:

Even better, get rid of those functions.  Functions in SQL always have the bad code smell of a DBA who is not yet thinking in sets.  I'm sure there is a faster way to get those values.

```
SELECT 
  [rownum],
  dbo.funcSellIdByPropId(T0.id) as SellerId,  
  dbo.funcDefaultImage(T0.id, 1) as propImage,  
  dbo.funcDefaultImage(T0.id, 2) as propImage2,  
  dbo.funcDefaultImage(T0.id, 3) as propImage3,  
  dbo.funcDefaultImage(T0.id, 4) as propImage4,  
  dbo.funcCountPropertyImages(T0.id) as imageCount,  
  dbo.funcGetPropertyTypeListGB(T0.id) as TypeGB,  
  dbo.funcGetPropertyTypeListFR(T0.id) as TypeFR,  
  dbo.funcGetPropertyEnviListGB(T0.id) as EnviGB,  
  dbo.funcGetPropertyEnviListFR(T0.id) as EnviFR,  
  dbo.funcGetDepartmentByTown(T0.Town) as Department,  
  dbo.funcCheckFeaturedProperty(T0.id) as Featured,  
  T0.id, T0.Price, T0.BedRooms, T0.Town, T0.Postcode,
  T0.Mandate, T0.MinLandArea, T0.Rooms, T0.HabitableSurface, 
  T0.Active, T0.Budget,  
  T1.TitleFR, T1.TitleGB, SUBSTRING(T1.DescFR, 0, 300) as DescFR,
  SUBSTRING(T1.DescGB, 0, 300) as DescGB  
  FROM  
(
 SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @SORTBY + ') AS [rownum],  *  
 FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT  
              T0.id

          FROM  
              PROPERTIES T0
              INNER JOIN PROPERTYTRANSLATIONS T1 ON T1.PropertyId = T0.id  
              INNER JOIN MATRIXPROPENVIRONMENT T2 ON T2.PropertyId = T0.id
              INNER JOIN ENVIRONMENT T3 ON T3.id = T2.EnvironmentId  
          WHERE  
              T0.Deleted = 0    
              AND T0.Active = 1   
              AND T3.GB IN (' + @FILTERBY + ')  
    ) T ) TT  
  WHERE  rownum BETWEEN (' + CONVERT(varchar(4), @PERPAGE * @PAGENUM) + ') 
    AND (' +   CONVERT(varchar(4), @PERPAGE * (@PAGENUM + 1)) + ')'
) TTT
JOIN PROPERTIES T0 ON T0.id = TTT.id
JOIN PROPERTYTRANSLATIONS T1 ON T1.PropertyId = T0.id
```

Comment: Good answer about not running the func against all rows when you won't be returning them.

Also: don't use dynamic SQL statements whenever possible.  If you made this a TVF or a stored proc then SQL Server could cache the plan for it more easily.

Comment: @jhilden - This query will be compiled and cached if it uses a parametrized query.  It should have the same performance as a SP after the first call.

Comment: Fan bloody tastic. I had to alter what you put there a little but it runs under a second again now and holds all the same functions! God send. Thank you so much!

Comment: @TheAngrySaxon - glad to hear it, good luck, and get rid of all those functions!

Comment: When you say thinking in set's what do you mean? Just out of curiosity? I'm very much a LINQ kinda guy so any sort of SQL SP tips would go a long way.

Comment: @TheAngrySaxon - Sure, post the code for dbo.funcDefaultImage or any of the other functions on code review and I will show you what I mean.  Oh... email or comment here with a link so I can find it.

Comment: Thanks again. The link is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46094/the-use-of-database-sets-rather-than-functions

Comment: @Hogan sorry that last message was meant for you